# ArcGIS Pro Script Tool Validation Not Updating Values in Tool

Tags: python, arcgis-pro, python-script-tool, tool-validation

I have an ArcGIS Pro toolbox tool based on a python script and am trying to have tool validation pre-fill values based on the location of the ArcGIS Toolbox location.  Here is a screenshot of the tool:

[image]

This is my validation python code:

```
def updateParameters(self):
    """Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
    validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parameter
    has been changed."""

    rootpathname = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath("__file__"))
    shorepathname = os.path.join(rootpathname, "Data\\Shoreline.gdb")
    templatepathname = os.path.join(rootpathname, "Symbology\\Representation Templates")


    if not self.params[1].altered:
        self.params[1].value = shorepathname

    if not self.params[3].altered:
        self.params[3].value = templatepathname

    return
```

When I run the tool, neither of the parameters have been updated with the validation values; they simply remain blank.  Why are my parameter values not updating?

Comment: Have you solved this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to set defaults, i.e "pre-filled", just set them directly in `getParameterInfo`

e.g.

```
def getParameterInfo(self):
    #Define parameter definitions

    # First parameter
    param0 = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName="Input Features",
        name="in_features",
        datatype="GPFeatureLayer",
        parameterType="Required",
        direction="Input")

    param0.value = "blah"  # <=== Set default value

    return [param0]
```

`updateParameters` isn't changing your empty values because it doesn't fire until a parameter gets altered.

Comment: I tried this, and the parameters are still all blank when I open the tool.

Comment: @spaine this is directly from the [documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/geoprocessing_and_python/defining-parameters-in-a-python-toolbox.htm) and definitely works. In my test tool, the parameters are filled when I open it. If yours do not, you have something not quite right. Edit your question and include your `getParameterInfo` code.

Comment: I've changed the nature of the question to identifying the location of ArcToolbox in Pro.  The rest of the script is now working.

Comment: Please don't change your question after someone has answered it, Ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Per [ESRI Documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/geoprocessing_and_python/customizing-tool-behavior-in-a-python-toolbox.htm), a list of parameters should be passed to the *updateParameters* method: This should be the same list returned by the *getParameterInfo* method. Then *updateParameters* looks like this (note that keyword "self" is not used):

```
def updateParameters(self, parameters):
    """doc string"""
    if not parameters[1].altered:
        parameters[1].value = shorepathname

    if not parameters[3].altered:
        parameters[3].value = templatepathname

return
```